Google api update reccurent events
I'm trying to update a recurrent event, for example, which was created on 04/08/2024, the update date is 04/10/2024. As I understand from the documentation, I must change the recurrence marked UNTIL to the time when the change occurred. And for subsequent meetings, I simply create them via insert . But here I have a problem when I try to delete events marked ALL_EVENTS, they are deleted either before or after the change. This raises the question: how can I make a request to update THIS_AND_FOLLOWING events so that later, when deleted via reccurentEventUd, they will all be deleted. In short there was a connection between them
I tried to create Eveets by linking them with etag, but when I deleted them using the mainId event, nothing happened
public Event createEventWithDataV2(
        CreateMeetingDto dto,
        String email,
        List<MeetingParticipant> meetingParticipants,
        String etag,
        String oldId
) {
    Event event = new Event();
    String newId = generateEventIdWithTimestamp(oldId);
    event.setId(newId);
    CalendarUtil.setGeneralInfo(event, dto.getTitle(), dto.getDescription());
    CalendarUtil.setEventDateTime(event, dto.getStartDate(), dto.getStartTime(), dto.getEndTime());
    CalendarUtil.setOrganizerCreatorRecurrence(event, email, dto.getRecurrence());
    CalendarUtil.setAttendees(event, email, meetingParticipants);
    CalendarUtil.setAttachmentsDTO(event, dto.getAttachments());
    event.setEtag(etag);

    if (dto.getLocation() != null) {
        event.setLocation(dto.getLocation());
    }

    return event;
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
